# comment reply system with catching specific id value

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

hi guys I have a blog post page and comment and reply system. Everything works fine except one thing:

When I try to add a reply to a comment, I am always replying to the first comment. I think my fault is I can't reach the specific comment id when I click. Here is my html and ajax code:

HTML CODE

```
    <div class="card" style=" margin-bottom:30px;">
    <div class="card-header">
        <a class="h3">@Model.Header</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-xl-12">
                <p style="font-size:small">
                    <b>Kategori: </b> @Model.Category.CategoryName ,<b>Makale Sayısı :</b> @Model.Category.Articles.Count()
                    <b>Yorum Sayısı :</b> @Model.Comments.Count() <br />
                    <b>Yayımlanma Tarihi: </b> @String.Format("{0: d MMMM yyyy}", Model.Date) ,<b>Etiketler:</b><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> @Model.Tags.Count()


                </p>
                <p style="font-size:small;">
                    <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" style="width:100px;height:100px;" src="@Model.User.Photo" alt="@Model.User.FullName" />
                    Posted by:
                    <a href="/User/UserProfile/@Model.User.UserId">@Model.User.UserName</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-xl-12">
                <img id="articlephoto" style="width:100%; height:350px" class="rounded float-left" src="@Model.Photo" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-xl-12">
                <p>@Html.Raw(Model.Paragraph)</p>
                <p style="font-size:small">
                    <b>Etiketler:</b>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Tags)
                    {
                    <span class="tag">@item.TagName,</span>
                    }
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<h4>Comments</h4>
<hr />
@foreach (var item in Model.Comments.ToList())
{
    <!-- Single Comment -->
    <div class="media mb-4">
        <img style="height:40px; width:40px;" class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="@item.User.Photo" alt="@item.User.FullName">
        <div class="media-body" style="width:400px;">
            <h5 class="mt-0">@item.User.UserName</h5>
            <p style="word-break:break-all">
                @item.Paragraph
                @if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]) == item.UserId)
                {
                    <a class="btn btn-danger"  href="/Home/DeleteComment/@item.CommentId">
                        Delete
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-warning replybutton" href="#replyform">
                        Reply
                    </a>
                }
            </p>
            <p style="font-size:small"><b>Yorum Tarihi:</b>@String.Format("{0: d MMMM yyyy}", item.Date)</p>

            <span id="astar" class=""> @item.CommentId</span>

            @foreach (var reply in Model.ReplyComments.Where(x => x.CommentId == item.CommentId).ToList())
            {
                <div class="media mt-4">
                    <img style="height:40px; width:40px;" class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="@item.User.Photo" alt="@item.User.FullName">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">@reply.User.UserName</h5>
                        <p>@reply.Paragraph</p>
                        @if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]) == item.UserId)
                        {
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/Home/DeleteReply/@reply.ReplyCommentId">
                                Sil
                            </a>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
}
@if (Session["UserId"] != null)
{
            <!-- Comments Form -->
    <div id="commentform" class="card my-4">
        <h5 class="card-header">Yorum Yap:</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="comment" typeof="text" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-primary">Yorum Yap</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="replyform" class="card my-4 d-none">
        <h5 class="card-header">Cevap Yaz:</h5>
        <div class="card-body">

            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="replytext" name="replytext" typeof="text" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="reply" name="reply" class="btn btn-primary">Cevap Yaz</button>

        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3 class="alert- alert-heading">Yorum Yapabilmek İçin Üye Girişi Yapmalısınız.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

AND my javascript ajax code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#reply").click(function (e) {

            var r_comment = $("#replytext").val();
            var r_commentid = parseInt($("#astar").html());

             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Home/ReplyComment/',
                 data: { replycomment: r_comment, articleid:@Model.ArticleId, commentid: r_commentid },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Cevap gönderildi");
                    window.location.reload();

                }
            });



    });
    })
</script>
```

My problem is that I can't catch the specific comment id when I click the reply button. I am getting the comment id from `<span id="astar" class=""> @item.CommentId</span>`

Comment: You are creating the `span` in a loop. Each time using the same `id`. Ids should be unique, hence `$("#astar")` will always find the first match and ignores the others. - Also, instead of posting the code you use to make the HTML you should post the actual **rendered** HTML and add that to a working code snippet. It looks like you have a single reply button for a collection of comments, how do you determine which comment to add the reply to with a single button?

Comment: So how can l catch any suggest ?

Comment: If you have 5 people named "Bob" is a room and you yell for "Bob" what is going to happen?

Comment: No where in the code you have the ability to tell what the user clicked. I am guessing you should use a radio button to select the item you want to comment with. Or you can do it with code to denote that you picked.

Comment: Also, as already mentioned in your last post, use `text()` instead of `.html()` in this case or maybe you can place the comment-id into a `data-comment-id` attribute on a reply button for each comment? Either way the design looks a bit off as it seems you have 1 reply button for many comments but yet require to reply to an exact comment...

Comment: how can l create a unıque id for span or should l look another way to solve this

Comment: on my comment system  there is one main comment and comment has replies...

Comment: But it looks like your code only rendered a single reply button after all comments and all replies are rendered. If that is so, how do you know when clicking the reply button which one of the many comments you reply to.

Comment: there is my problem l cant choose the comment which l want to reply.  and l have no idea  how can l choose my brain stopped :)

Comment: I can't really help you much with brain storming design ideas. It's your blog post page. Ignore the code and work out how you want it to work functionality from a usability point of view. Make yourself a user story and ones you find a workflow you are happy with start coding it.

Answer (score 0):

"When I try to add a reply to a comment, I am always replying to the first comment. " - it's because all your comments have the same ID and jQuery selects the first matching element.

All comments need to have a unique ID. I don't know what language that loop is in but you need to increment the ID. So `astar-1`, `astar-2`, `astar-3` etc...

Example;

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var valueBox = document.getElementById('value-box');
  $('.reply').on('click', function(){
    var comment = $(this).prev().attr('id');
    valueBox.innerHTML += '<br />Reply to comment: ' + comment;
    console.log(comment);
  });
});
```

```css
.comment::after {
  display: table;
  content: ' ';
  clear: both;
 }

span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}

.reply {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment">
  <span id="comment-1">Yorum 1</span>
  <div class="reply">Cevapla</div>
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <span id="comment-2">Yorum 2</span>
  <div class="reply">Cevapla</div>
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <span id="comment-3">Yorum 3</span>
  <div class="reply">Cevapla</div>
</div>

<div id="value-box">
</div>
```

Comment: l did this  l just changed the <span id="@item.commentId"  </span>  now l can generate unıque ıd for each comment but l couldnt take span id value on javascript side

Comment: You might need to change your structure. You need to have the reply button on each comment as well. And do the click event on the reply button class and get the span element from that context. Look at the snippet I provided.

Comment: ok l just solved the problem ı just moved my reply form into the foreach and problem is fixed

Comment: Good. Kolay gelsin :)